# Call angular service request in another js file

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, three.js

I have several html and typescript files in my angular project and I have a package dedicated to `three.js` graphics part. I need to call a function from a Service in my `Canvas.js` file to make a `GET` request to database and make 3d objects from that data request.

**item.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './item';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemService {

  item: Item;
  private itemURL = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getItemById(_id: string): Observable<string> {
    const url = `${this.item}/${_id}`;
    return this.http.get<string>(url);
  }
```

**Canvas.js**

```
function onLoad() {
    // var injector = angular.element(document).injector()

    angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get("ItemService").getItemById(13);
    //possible alternatives
    //angular.element(document).find('body').injector().get("ItemService");  
    //getSrv("ItemService", document.body);


    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

I need to call `getItemById()` method in `Canvas.js` and save that data into a variable and use its attributes.

Also: [my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnVua.png)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if angular itself exposes it's injector, but you can try to do it when your app starts via binding injector to window. Although it seems like a bad and insecure idea. Because later anyone in browser console will be able to access your application injector container. Maybe you should think about moving your Canvas.js logic into angular?

Comment: I have this html element <button class="preview" id="preview" onclick="window.open('app/graphics/index.html', 'visualização', 'width=800,height=600')">Pré-visualizar</button> to open the window with graphics. How do I bind the inject to that window?

Comment: I would suggest a different implementation. In my opinion, you need a better integration with three. I would create an angular component that wraps your three code into a reusable component. Then instead of opening a window for your graphic you would simply have an angular route. This will open the door to better variable binding abilities between Angular and your Canvas.js script. Sorry I don't have time to put together a formal example and answer.

Comment: to add, it looks like your Canvas.js functionality is writtenn to work with AngularJS, not Angular. there's no `[ng-app]` or `angular.element` in Angular 2+.